# Highlight fields in standerd page layout in lightning

Tags: lightning

I have some confidential fields, and I want to highlight them when the record is edited.
We are using a standard case object, and it's a standard page layout.
We don't want to override the edit functionality just for highlighting. Hoping someone has a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can not highlight them in a better way than putting them together into a separate section or create a custom component to override edit action.
I believe that once [Dynamic Forms on Case](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000lfS6QAI) are delivered it will be easier to achieve such requirements.